# matlab GUI Multiple choice test and radiobuttons

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am new to GUI in matlab and i am learning it. There is a question that I searched the world to find the answer but I couldn't.

I am trying to create a GUI with a test of multiple choices.

For the start there are 6 questions.

The answer for each question is in a **Button Group**.

Every Button Group is named as "answer1" answer2....answer6 (and tagged like this).

Each Button Group has 3 **RadioButtons**. Every Radiobutton is tagged "radiobutton1",2,3.

There is also a **PushButton** tagged as "Submit" and a **Static Text** which will display the correct answers.

First of all. Lets say (for the test) that only the radiobutton1 is the correct answer for every question. Is it correct to write the code like this:

```
function answer1_SelectionChangeFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if hObject==handles.radiobutton1
    answer1=correct;
else
    wrong;
end
```

???

Secondly, How to collect the answers from each question as correct or wrong with the **Submit** button?

Finally, how can I display the answers in the static text field (tagged as **corrects**)?

I would appreciate if someone could answer to these.

Comment: You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624438/how-can-i-get-the-selected-value-of-radio-button

Comment: thnx.but it didn't help much.

Comment: @Tony why didn't it help? What issues did you run into?

Comment: Because I don't get the philosophy behind the coding there.I don't understand what does what and why it is this way...And of course doesn't help me with my question which is very clear.